# Mongo DB connection via pymongo in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am newbie in MongoDB and tried to implement a code for connecting mongo via Python. I used pymongo package from standard python user manual. And choose mlab for this purpose.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('mongodb://test:test@account.mlab.com:port',
                     connectTimeoutMS=300000,maxPoolSize=50)

print(client)
```

> MongoClient(host=['account.mlab.com:port'], 
>               document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, **connect=True**, maxpoolsize=50, connecttimeoutms=300000)

Clearly, i can see connection is successful. Now, lets check database

```
db=client.get_database(test) // Specifying a DB
```

print(db)

> Database(MongoClient(host=['account.mlab.com:port'],
>                        document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, 
>                        **connect=True**, connecttimeoutms=300000), **u'test'**)

Confirming connection is successful with selected test DB.

```
users = db.users // Selecting a collection
print(users)
```

> Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['ds024778.mlab.com:24778'], 
>                                   document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, 
>                                   **connect=True**, connecttimeoutms=300000), **u'test**'), **u'users'**)

Now, I am trying to get a document in users where `username = 'admin'`

```
r = users.find_one({"username":'admin'})
```

But, Error

**`OperationFailure: Authentication failed.`**

Comment: Is your user allowed to perform specified action on `users` collection? Check [collection level access control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/collection-level-access-control/) for more info!

Comment: under user, 
     "roles": [
        {
            "role": "dbOwner",
            "db": "test"
        }
    ]

Comment: What server logs say? Do you escape login/password? Can you find the user from mongo shell?  `mongo "mongodb://test:test@ds024778.mlab.com:24778"` doesn't work.

Comment: sorry, i am connecting to cloud and can't install mongo client on system

Comment: install it locally, or in a docker

Comment: are you able to access any other collection data if present?

Comment: as i type : client = MongoClient('mongodb://test:test@account.mlab.com:port\test',
                     connectTimeoutMS=300000,maxPoolSize=50)  all is well !!